# Unable to load bulma calendar extension

Tags: javascript, bulma

In a new laravel project, I installed bulma-calendar using `npm install bulma-calendar --save-dev`. In my app.scss file, I am importing both bulma and bulma-calendar like this:

```
@import "~bulma";
@import "~bulma-calendar";
```

and in the bootstrap.js file at the top of the file I imported the minified js file:

```
import bulmaCalendar from 'bulma-calendar/dist/bulma-calendar.min.js'
```

and at the bottom of it I added this:

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var datePicker = new bulmaCalendar( document.getElementById( 'datepickerDemo' ), {
    startDate: new Date(), // Date selected by default
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd', // the date format `field` value
    lang: 'en', // internationalization
    overlay: false,
    closeOnOverlayClick: true,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    // callback functions
    onSelect: null,
    onOpen: null,
    onClose: null,
    onRender: null
  } );
  var datePicker = new bulmaCalendar( document.getElementById( 'datepickerDemo2' ), {
    overlay: true
  } );
} );
```

And in my welcome.blade.php I added an input element:

```
<input id="datepickerDemo" class="input" type="text" value="11-02-2018">
```

But I don't see any calendar when I click on that input field, just as I see on the [demo](https://wikiki.github.io/components/calendar/) page. What am I missing?

Also, in the console, I am seeing this error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_bulma_calendar_dist_bulma_calendar_min___default.a is not a constructor
```

Comment: I had issues getting the demo date-picker working and found I had to load the bulma-calendar.js file directly - there was a conflict that wouldn't allow the "bulmaCalendar" class to be found when used in conjunction with  webpack

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would do the trick, but change the input type from "text" to "date"

```
<input id="datepickerDemo" class="input" type="date" value="11-02-2018">
```

Source: https://demo.creativebulma.net/components/calendar/v6/#html-structure

Answer (score 0):

Hello i'm use laravel 6 and i had the same issue. But i found a way to resolve it and now bulma calendar work perfectly in my project.

/resources/sass/app.scss

```
// Import component 
@import "bulma-calendar";
```

/resources/js/app.js :
put this on top

```
var bulmaCalendar=require('bulma-calendar');
```

after this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

// Initialize all input of type date
var calendars = bulmaCalendar.attach('[type="date"]', []);

// Loop on each calendar initialized
for(var i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
    // Add listener to date:selected event
    calendars[i].on('select', date => {
        console.log(date);
    });
}

// To access to bulmaCalendar instance of an element
var element = document.querySelector('#my-element');
if (element) {
    // bulmaCalendar instance is available as element.bulmaCalendar
    element.bulmaCalendar.on('select', function(datepicker) {
        console.log(datepicker.data.value());
    });
}
});
```

in my view blade.php

```
`<input type="date">`
```

It's work for me i hope that it will help you

Answer (score 0):

For an example like yours i've try this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    bulmaCalendar.attach('#datepickerDemoDefault', {
        displayMode: 'dialog',
        startDate: new Date(),
        minDate: '01/01/2020',
        maxDate: '12/31/2500',
        lang: 'fr'
    });

    const element = document.querySelector('#datepickerDemoDefault');

    if (element) {
        // bulmaCalendar instance is available as element.bulmaCalendar
        element.bulmaCalendar.on('select', function(datepicker) {
            console.log(datepicker.data.value());
        });
    }

});
```